# Using NOT predicates in SQL

Tags: sql, t-sql

I've created some queries and can't understand why the results are not as I expected.

I don't understand why Query II and III don't return the same results. I would expect query II to return all rows not selected by Query I.

I would have expected Query II and III to give the same results. In my opinion the results of III are the right ones.

I'm sure I miss something, I just don't know what.

The example:

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TestTable](
 [TestTableId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ValueA] [int] NULL,
 [ValueB] [int] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Data:

```
TestTableId ValueA ValueB
1        10      5
2        20      5
3        10      NULL
4        20        NULL
5        NULL      10
6        10        10
7        NULL      NULL
```

Queries:

All records:
    select * from TestTable

I. A select query:

```
select * from TestTable 
where (ValueA = 10 or ValueA = 20) AND ValueB = 5
```

Result:

```
TestTableId ValueA ValueB
1           10   5
2           20   5
```

II. The same query but as NOT

```
select * from TestTable 
where NOT ((ValueA = 10 or ValueA = 20) AND ValueB = 5)
```

Result:

```
TestTableId ValueA ValueB
5           NULL   10
6           10   NULL
```

III. The same query as the second (I would think)

```
select * from TestTable where TestTable.TestTableId not in 
    (select TestTableId from TestTable 
where (ValueA = 10 or ValueA = 20) AND ValueB = 5)
```

Result:

```
TestTableId ValueA ValueB
3           10   NULL
4           20   NULL
5           NULL   10
6           10   10
7           NULL   NULL
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

NULLs are funny creatures. They will answer "I don't know" to both of the following questions:

```
Are you 5?  (... WHERE ValueB = 5)
```

and

```
Are you Not 5? (... WHERE NOT ValueB = 5)
```

Which results in NULL values being excluded from *both* queries, as you found.

You have to ask the question in a way that explicitly accounts for the NULLs:

```
... WHERE (ValueB IS NULL OR NOT ValueB = 5) ...
```

Comment: `NULL = 5` evaluates to `UNKNOWN` (rather than "no").

Comment: I was being a bit metaphorical. The point is that a row where ValueB is NULL will be excluded from both.

Comment: @onedaywhen - Edited my post to be slightly more precise based on your comment.

Answer (score 2):

When using `NOT`, `NULL` values are a special situation.

A `NULL` is an **unknown** value.  SQL can't say if it's `NOT` a 12, but it can say if it **is** a 12.

A good example:

You are at a party.  You know 2 of the 12 people's names in the room, both are named John.  You can tell me who the "John"s are.  You **can't** tell me who is "Not Jack" besides  the 2 "John"s.  For SQL, those other 10 people in the room have a name of `NULL`.